# Spring handler mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, handler

I'm new to Spring MVC.

I have URLs like this:

- localhost:8080/spring-mvc-project-web-war/searchProjects
- localhost:8080/spring-mvc-project-web-war/searchProjects/

The difference is the "/" at the end of each URL.

Both render a page with the same content. The content includes a search button, which will search through database and return a list of results. But the first URL always returns `HTTP 404 - /spring-mvc-project-web-war/searchProjects` and the second still works fine.

Can anyone explain this for me?

I know this is the problem of handler mapping but I don't really understand it clearly.

Comment: Could you please post your web.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's none of Spring HandlerMapping business.

when you click search button, the form http url posted depends on http base uri and your relative path(usually in action attribute)

"localhost:8080/spring-mvc-project-web-war/searchProjects" it's base uri is

```
localhost:8080/spring-mvc-project-web-war/
```

and "localhost:8080/spring-mvc-project-web-war/searchProjects/" base uri is

```
localhost:8080/spring-mvc-project-web-war/searchProjects/
```

In order to further understand，we can read Fielding's 
[rfc document [Page 11]](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt)